# How do I define a relationship between activerecord and activeresource using foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, activeresource

I have a local user model which uses activerecord. The user has an email field. I also have an activeresource model called tasks which has a created_by field which stores the submitting users email address. I'd like to link the two but I'm struggling with the right syntax or even whether it's possible.

The main branch of ActiveResource doesn't even seem to support foreign key. I found an [alternative branch](https://github.com/sephinroth/activeresource/commit/bd74cf238e8f78b49917339ef12b77da91080ae9) but still couldn't get anything working.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveResource::Base
  belongs_to :user
  schema do
    string 'created_by' #email
    # other fields
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code should work fine given that you have a `user_id` attribute on the `Task` to act as the foreign key, or you can specify the foreign key in the association on `User` model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, foreign_key: "uid"
end
```

Now the problem is, you can't use `belongs_to` on `ActiveResource` so unless you need to retrieve the `user` from an instance of the `Task` class, you can just remove it and the other side of the relation will still work, however, if you need to retrieve the `user` then you'd have to either implement your own finder method as follows:

```
class Task < ActiveResource::Base
  schema do
    string 'created_by' #email
    # other fields
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find self.user_id # use the attribute name that represents the foreign key
  end

  def user=(user)
    @user = user
    self.update_attribute(:user_id, user.id)
  end
end
```

This will basically behave the same as you would expect on an `ActiveRecord` model, however this can be tiresome if you have multiple associations so you can instead extend the `ActiveResource` module to add `belongs_to` as follows:

```
module BelongsToActiveResource

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods

    def belongs_to( name, options = {} )
      class_eval %(
        def #{name}
          @#{name} ||= name.to_s.classify.find( name.id )
        end

        def #{name}=(obj)
          @#{name} ||= obj
          self.update_attribute((name.to_s + "_id").to_sym, @#{name}.id
        end
      )
    end

  end

end   

ActiveResource::Base.class_eval { include BelongsToActiveResource }
```

This will allow you to use belongs_to on any `ActiveResource` model.

P.S.: the above solution was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844932/3770684

Comment: I tried this with the monkey patch you suggested but when I run 'User.last.tasks' I get 'NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Task:Class'

Comment: Which versions of ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.1.0 and Ruby 2.1.1

Comment: Sorry its been a while, I'll try building a dummy for it cause I cant recreate on Rails 4.0 and update my solution

Comment: I'll award the 50 points for effort then, before they run out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can fake it by implementing accessor methods yourself.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has_many :tasks
  def tasks
    Task.find(:all, params: {created_by: email})
  end
end

class Task < ActiveResource::Base
  #belongs_to :user
  def user
    User.where(email: created_by).first
  end

  schema do
    string 'created_by' #email
    # other fields
  end
end
```

This will let you write code *as if* your objects were associated (i.e. `User.first.tasks.length`). However, they aren't actually joined. That means calling `User.first.tasks` is going to hit the database, then make an additional HTTP request to retrieve the Tasks. Depending on how your code is structured, you could run into unexpected performance issues.

Also, you can't run a single query to get a User *and* all associated Tasks (since it's two separate data stores), and you can't do fancy stuff like `User.joins(:tasks).where({tasks: field_1: true})`.